# Telerik MVC grid problems

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid

Ok, Telerik has some good visual appealing controls, but it damn hard to use and too diferent from html programming.

My problem:
I had in my page a grid with ajax turned on. So sorting, paging.. are made with ajax calls to my controllers.
In this page there is a link to open a window (telerik one..), this windows is opened with this javascript code:

```
 $(".bs-icon").live("click", function () {

    var windowElement = $.telerik.window.create({
        Name: "myWindow",
        title: "Pesquisa",
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: true,
        scrollable: false,
        visible: false,
        width: 500,
        height: 400,
        onClose: function () { }
    });

    var w = windowElement.data("tWindow");
    w.ajaxRequest("Alerts/IndexLookup/");
    w.center().open();
});
```

In this window there is another grid, but I can´t get the ajax to work with this second grid. Something is turned off and I don´t know what it is.

Thanks.

Changed the javascript to this:

```
$.get("/AlertaGeral/IndexLookup",
        function (response) {
            $("#form-temp").html(response);
        });
    return false;
```

to get off telerik windows. Same problem.
The grid that comes from ajax request does not works properly. Maybe some setup is missing after including it in the page.

---

Here is AlertaGeralController:

```
    public ActionResult IndexLookup(Consulta.FiltroPadrao filtro = null)
    {
        if (Session["token"] == null)
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

        if (filtro == null)
            filtro = new Consulta.FiltroPadrao { Descricao = null };

        ResultadoPadrao[] registros = consulta.Pesquisar(Session["token"].ToString(), "SamAlertageral", filtro);

        Session["ultimoFiltro"] = filtro;

        return PartialView("_GridPesquisaLookup", registros);
    }
```

and the view _GridPesquisaLookup.cshtml:

```
@model  Benner.Saude.Consulta.ResultadoPadrao[]


@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(c => c.Handle))         
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding
        .Ajax()
        .Select("AjaxPesquisarLookup", "AlertaGeral")
            )
    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "grid-padrao" })        
    .ClientEvents(events => events
        .OnDataBound("atualizarCss")
        .OnRowSelect("selecionarRegistro")
    )        
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound("Descricao").Title("Descrição");
        columns.Bound("Handle").Title("Código");            
    })        
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()

    )
```

Comment: Have you tried to parse your new grid without using telerik Window? Just to eliminate a few possibilities :)

Comment: And you should change the title of your question. It's too general!

Comment: Same problem. I change my javascript. See above.

Comment: Now we know that its not a Window problem. Can you give use the code that you have inside /AlertaGeral/IndexLookup ?

Comment: Hi Alexandre, I edit the question. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a conflic somewhere in your View. Here something you can do to find your problem:

Create a View that will only show your _GridPesquisaLookup.cshtml without any ajax. That way, you will be able to test ONLY this grid. Use Html.Partial("_GridPesquisaLookup") in your View.

- **If the grid work**, its because there's a conflic with the other View when you use two grids at the same time. **Maybe the two grids have the same name**. It happened to me a few months ago and i had the same problem as you.
- **If the grid does'nt work**, well you will know that your problem is from this grid. You will have to do more tests.

Comment: The problem is not the grid. The problem is bringing this grid via ajax, I think.. I need to call scriptRegistrar again ?

Comment: It depends. In my project, i have the same needs as you: bring a grid on request via Ajax. But since that you already have a grid in your View, the javascript files need for the grid should be already there. On my projects, i add manually all the Telerik scripts with the ScriptRegistrar. All my grids works perfectly, created with Ajax or not. This is why i suggest you to test your grid step by step.